# Please help me choose an ad selling platform to integrate with a website

Tags: web-development, advertising, ad-server

My team and I are currently building a website, and we’re looking into options for selling our ad space directly to whoever would like to purchase it. Not an exchange server like AdSense, but platform where we put our conditions and control our ad space. I’m honestly super lost with all those OpenX, PubMatic and other here-just-read-these-100500-pages-of-fancy-text-to-learn-about-our-services companies. Can anybody advice a good, paid service for us to implement to the website, so our clients can click button “buy ad space”, pay us and place their ads?